# Returning a HTTP 1xx code before the 200 one with WSGI

Tags: python, http, wsgi

I write a Python+WSGI application and I would like to return an interim 1xx status code such as 102 "Processing" or 103 "Early hints" with some headers, before returning the final 200 and the result body.

I know, that, to return data in several steps, my application needs to be iterable, for instance with yield (see [In WSGI, send response without returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041001/in-wsgi-send-response-without-returning) )

But all the examples I've found so far use only one status code. I find no way to change it. For instance, the code:

```
import wsgiref, wsgiref.simple_server, time

def app(environ, start):
    start('102 Processing', [('Foo', 'bar')])
    yield "More to come"
    time.sleep(2)

    start('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield "hello, world"

httpd = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('localhost', 8999, app)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Only send the 102 status code, and crashes when it is time to send the rest:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53540)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 131, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 92, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 33, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

Is there even a way in WSGI to do that?

Comment: According to the RFCs I've seen, this is supposedly possible, but I think the issue you have is sending a response (text) after the header then trying to send another header.  Try removing that first  'yield' before your timer and see if that stops the error.   The interim headers are only allowed to send codes 100-199 so you should be OK as long as you you send 1xx codes only before the  2xx,3xx,4xx or 5xx response headers.  At least that's the way it read to me.

Comment: @DDeMartini Sorry, deleting the first yield changed nothing.

Comment: The error is because "it is a fatal error to call start_response without the exc_info argument if start_response has already been called" (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#the-start-response-callable). I am not sure WSGI supports what you want.

Comment: I suspected that it was an illegal operation, but not being totally familiar with WSGI, I wasn't sure.  I know that Perl and PHP will both hurl expletives about having a header already started, but it seems the RFCs say it should be possible... but we all know RFCs are not really the final word on how certain software implements anything (just like at historical trash from M$ like IE)

Comment: A workaround may be to use the deprecated way as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775731/6368697 and explained here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#the-write-callable  ; also is it sure that the client application deals correctly with the 1XX headers? In a (long) past I did not have a lot of luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At the WSGI application level this is not possible.

The status and headers can only be changed up to the point before the first response content is yielded, but at that point there is nothing yet allowed to be sent back to the client, so it can't be used to send multiple status and headers, only replace what will be sent.